# I can't get Google Webmaster Tools to verify my site

Tags: meta-tags, verification, google-search-console

I want to add my domain [lslib.com](http://lslib.com) to Google Webmaster Tools but need to verify my domain.

I've tried the meta tag option, the Google Analytics option and the HTML file option, but nothing seems to work.

If you open the URL above and look at the source, the first meta tag exactly mirrors what Webmaster Tools is telling me:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="XWD_Tw7b5SaXpUTdGsBLb3zAIEyElTgmgou8wDZQ870" />
```

Only, why would this not work?

Answer (score 0):

If meta tag validation is not working, you can try with HTML file verification:

> Verify your site by uploading an HTML file:
>
> 1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the Manage Site button next to the site you want, and then click Verify this site.
> 2. If HTML file upload is not visible on the Recommended method tab, click the Alternate methods tab.
> 3. Select HTML file upload, and follow the steps on your screen.
> 4. Once the HTML file has been uploaded to the root of the website, click Verify.

Check this link form more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35658?hl=en